# Merging three tables by keeping all rows

Tags: r, merge

I have three sets of data.

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Pa  Gu  Ta
1123    16  14  13
                   1124 26  14  19
                   1125 14  29  25
                   1126 14  22  20
                   ")

dat1
    ID Pa Gu Ta
1 1123 16 14 13
2 1124 26 14 19
3 1125 14 29 25
4 1126 14 22 20

dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  De  Ep  Ti  ID1
1123    113 121 100 11231
                   1123 105 107 110 11232
                   1124 122 111 107 11241
                   1124 117 120 111 11242
                   1124 122 116 109 11243
                   1125 108 111 118 11251
                   1125 106 115 113 11252
                   1125 113 104 108 11253
                   1126 109 119 116 11261
                   ")
dat2
    ID  De  Ep  Ti   ID1
1 1123 113 121 100 11231
2 1123 105 107 110 11232
3 1124 122 111 107 11241
4 1124 117 120 111 11242
5 1124 122 116 109 11243
6 1125 108 111 118 11251
7 1125 106 115 113 11252
8 1125 113 104 108 11253
9 1126 109 119 116 11261

dat3 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  So  Re  Ai  ID1
1123    115 102 121 11231
                   1123 106 116 111 11232
                   1124 117 109 102 11241
                   1124 101 108 113 11242
                   1124 120 101 115 11243
                   1124 120 111 119 11244
                   1124 106 122 107 11245
                   ")
dat3
    ID  So  Re  Ai   ID1
1 1123 115 102 121 11231
2 1123 106 116 111 11232
3 1124 117 109 102 11241
4 1124 101 108 113 11242
5 1124 120 101 115 11243
6 1124 120 111 119 11244
7 1124 106 122 107 11245
```

I want to merge these three dataset by `ID`. Here's my code:

```
t1 <- merge(dat1, dat2, by="ID")
t2 <- merge(t1, dat3, by="ID")

t2
     ID Pa Gu Ta  De  Ep  Ti ID1.x  So  Re  Ai ID1.y
1  1123 16 14 13 113 121 100 11231 115 102 121 11231
2  1123 16 14 13 113 121 100 11231 106 116 111 11232
3  1123 16 14 13 105 107 110 11232 115 102 121 11231
4  1123 16 14 13 105 107 110 11232 106 116 111 11232
5  1124 26 14 19 122 111 107 11241 117 109 102 11241
6  1124 26 14 19 122 111 107 11241 101 108 113 11242
7  1124 26 14 19 122 111 107 11241 120 101 115 11243
8  1124 26 14 19 122 111 107 11241 120 111 119 11244
9  1124 26 14 19 122 111 107 11241 106 122 107 11245
10 1124 26 14 19 117 120 111 11242 117 109 102 11241
11 1124 26 14 19 117 120 111 11242 101 108 113 11242
12 1124 26 14 19 117 120 111 11242 120 101 115 11243
13 1124 26 14 19 117 120 111 11242 120 111 119 11244
14 1124 26 14 19 117 120 111 11242 106 122 107 11245
15 1124 26 14 19 122 116 109 11243 117 109 102 11241
16 1124 26 14 19 122 116 109 11243 101 108 113 11242
17 1124 26 14 19 122 116 109 11243 120 101 115 11243
18 1124 26 14 19 122 116 109 11243 120 111 119 11244
19 1124 26 14 19 122 116 109 11243 106 122 107 11245
```

It clearly merges the dataset by common ID. But the first two datset has two `ID`s `(1125, 1126)` and have some merged output that is missing because `dat3` doesn't have these `ID`s. I want these merged data in my final output like the following:

```
ID  Pa  Gu  Ta  De  Ep  Ti  ID1.x   So  Re  Ai  ID1.y
1123    16  14  13  113 121 100 11231   115 102 121 11231
1123    16  14  13  113 121 100 11231   106 116 111 11232
1123    16  14  13  105 107 110 11232   115 102 121 11231
1123    16  14  13  105 107 110 11232   106 116 111 11232
1124    26  14  19  122 111 107 11241   117 109 102 11241
1124    26  14  19  122 111 107 11241   101 108 113 11242
1124    26  14  19  122 111 107 11241   120 101 115 11243
1124    26  14  19  122 111 107 11241   120 111 119 11244
1124    26  14  19  122 111 107 11241   106 122 107 11245
1124    26  14  19  117 120 111 11242   117 109 102 11241
1124    26  14  19  117 120 111 11242   101 108 113 11242
1124    26  14  19  117 120 111 11242   120 101 115 11243
1124    26  14  19  117 120 111 11242   120 111 119 11244
1124    26  14  19  117 120 111 11242   106 122 107 11245
1124    26  14  19  122 116 109 11243   117 109 102 11241
1124    26  14  19  122 116 109 11243   101 108 113 11242
1124    26  14  19  122 116 109 11243   120 101 115 11243
1124    26  14  19  122 116 109 11243   120 111 119 11244
1124    26  14  19  122 116 109 11243   106 122 107 11245
1125    14  29  25  108 111 118 11251               
1125    14  29  25  106 115 113 11252               
1125    14  29  25  113 104 108 11253               
1126    14  22  20  109 119 116 11261
```

Comment: `?merge` has an argument `all = TRUE` which you need here. You could also use `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "ID", all = TRUE), list(dat1, dat2, dat3))` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `merge` after placing the datasets in a `list`.  If we want to keep all the rows, `all=TRUE` (as @docendo discimus mentioned in the comments) or in this example `all.x=TRUE` would also get the expected output.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='ID', all.x=TRUE), list(dat1, dat2, dat3))
```